# Labeling moving object in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a sequence of 2D images in which there are several objects. Using background segmentation, I have correctly identified all the objects on the scene, and then classified them between moving/static objects.

The problem is that I have done this independently on each frame, but I would need to have a label for each object in each frame with a number for each one. Another problem I have is that objects can disappear from one frame to the other, so I would need to take this into consideration. For example, if I have objects 1, 2, 3 and 4, and then object 3 disappears, the labels should still be 1, 2 and 4.

For each frame, I have a struct with the following fields for each object, obtained with the function `regionprops`:

```
           Area: 24
       Centroid: [20.5000 11]
    BoundingBox: [8.5000 10.5000 24 1]
MajorAxisLength: 27.7128
MinorAxisLength: 1.1547
   PixelIdxList: [24x1 double]
      PixelList: [24x2 double]
       isStatic: 'No'
```

But I don't exactly know how to use this information in order to label the objects with a number that will stay the same all along the frames. Some objects can disappear, some can change a little bit their area/shape, and also some of them move around the image.

Comment: You may use `insertText` command   ( http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/inserttext.html )

Comment: Yeah that's good for the visualization, but I would like to have a way to label each object as a new field on the struct, and which is also consistent throughout the whole image sequence (meaning that if one object disappears from the screen, that object's number also disappears from the list).